# Why is my Python setup script failing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, distutils

I have a more complex project that I'm working on, and in an attempt to simplify things down to their essence to understand why things are failing, I made up the following project (the screen shot is from Eclipse)

This is the directory structure before running **setup.py sdist**
[image: Directory structure before running **setup sdist**]
Note that there are TWO projects here - the simple project (Deploy_Test) I'm using for testing the distribution process, and the *common* project containing the **class** and **function** packages that I expect to share across projects. On the right is the contents of my setup.py file

Here is the output from running **setup.py sdist**. Note the error line at the end called out by the red box:
[image: Output from running **setup.py sdist**]

Here are the results. Note the empty folders created (again called out by the red boxes). On the right you can see the contents of the MANIFEST file created:
[image: Results from running **setup.py sdist**]

My initial thought was that despite my referring to the referenced "classes" and "functions" packages in setup.py via the **package_dir** argument, that this was somehow causing a problem.

To test this, I copied and pasted the "classes" and "functions" packages into the **Deploy_Test** folder, removed the **package_dir** argument from setup.py, removed the MANIFEST file and empty folders, and re-ran **setup.py sdist**, and got similar results - the formerly "common" directory was missing, but the "classes" and "functions" directories now appear in the **Deploy_Test-1.0** directory, but are still empty, as is the **Deploy_Test** subdirectory below **Deploy_Test-1.0**.

I also still got the same error "Incorrect function" error message. I still don't understand what it's trying to tell me with that.

Thanks for any advice on this...

After getting @Cartroo's advice on this, I re-ran the process with the same structure on my local HD (NTFS). The "Incorrect function" error was indeed avoided, but now something else is screwing things up. Here is the output from **setup.py sdist**

```
running sdist
running check
writing manifest file 'MANIFEST'
creating Deployment Test-1.0
creating Common
creating Common\classes
creating Common\functions
creating Deployment Test-1.0\Deploy_Test
making hard links in Deployment Test-1.0...
hard linking setup.py -> Deployment Test-1.0
hard linking ..\Common\classes\__init__.py -> Deployment Test-1.0\..\Common\classes
hard linking ..\Common\classes\fw_ftp.py -> Deployment Test-1.0\..\Common\classes
hard linking ..\Common\functions\__init__.py -> Deployment Test-1.0\..\Common\functions
hard linking ..\Common\functions\fw_date.py -> Deployment Test-1.0\..\Common\functions
hard linking ..\Common\functions\fw_db.py -> Deployment Test-1.0\..\Common\functions
hard linking ..\Common\functions\fw_file.py -> Deployment Test-1.0\..\Common\functions
hard linking ..\Common\functions\fw_file_io.py -> Deployment Test-1.0\..\Common\functions
hard linking ..\Common\functions\fw_string.py -> Deployment Test-1.0\..\Common\functions
hard linking Deploy_Test\Deploy_Test.py -> Deployment Test-1.0\Deploy_Test
hard linking Deploy_Test\__init__.py -> Deployment Test-1.0\Deploy_Test
creating dist
creating 'dist\Deployment Test-1.0.zip' and adding 'Deployment Test-1.0' to it
adding 'Deployment Test-1.0\PKG-INFO'
removing 'Deployment Test-1.0' (and everything under it)
error removing Deployment Test-1.0: Deployment Test-1.0\Deploy_Test\Deploy_Test.py: The system cannot find the file specified
error removing Deployment Test-1.0: Deployment Test-1.0\Deploy_Test\__init__.py: The system cannot find the file specified
error removing Deployment Test-1.0: Deployment Test-1.0\Deploy_Test: The directory is not empty
error removing Deployment Test-1.0: Deployment Test-1.0\setup.py: The system cannot find the file specified
error removing Deployment Test-1.0: Deployment Test-1.0: The directory is not empty
```

The only thing contained in **dist/Deployment Test-1.0.zip** is a single file: PKG-INFO
All of the files that the errors claim can't be found all exist in the **Deployment Test-1.0 directory**. The **Common** project folders all were copied to their own subfolder below the /Deploy_Test folder, and the MANIFEST file appears to be correct (it includes all of the modules contained in the packages specified in setup.py)

Ha! Interesting! After going back to the USB drive and adding adding the two lines to setup.py suggested by @Cartroo, I got no errors - not even the errors that I was getting on my local HD about the files it couldn't find.

I'm not sure if I'm completely out of the woods yet, as the dist folder contains a zip file with only the Deploy_Test.py file within it. The process copied the Common/ folder to the Deploy_Test\ folder, and included a reference to the contents of the original Common/ folder (which exists collateral to the Deploy_Test folder) in the manifest file, but none of those modules got included into the dist folder, which I was expecting. However, considering I have no idea what a successful Python distribution looks like, I may be making an incorrect assumption

Answer (score 1):

From *memory* that "incorrect function" error is a Windows-specific one which is pretty generic and usually indicates that you're doing something unsupported by the system.

I notice that the message just prior to the error is about hard linking - I wonder if this only works on some filesystems. I suggest checking if you're using NTFS - if not, perhaps see if it's possible to create a small NTFS partition to try the build on (perhaps on a USB drive).

If it is related to the hard linking then [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue8876) may be relevant. If so, that would give you an easy thing to try - insert this *right* at the start of your `setup.py` and see if it helps (even before your first `import`):

```
import os
del os.link
```

Of course, this is based on a hunch and some vague memory of looking into that error for other reasons on Windows some time ago. However, at least inserting those two lines is something you can very easily attempt. I'm also not suggesting that this is a robust and portable way of fixing the issue, but at least whether it changes the error you're seeing might give you information about whether it's at least related.

Comment: Thanks - what's interesting is I'm running this from a USB drive (it allows me to work on this on either my desktop computer at the office, or my laptop at home). My first thought before you mentioning trying to run it from a USB drive is to copy the structure to my local HD (which IS NTFS) to see if that avoids the problem. I'll try this first, then adding the two lines you suggest to my setup.py and report back if either fix corrects the problem.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - if you haven't reformatted it, USB drives are generally pre formatted to FAT or VFAT, which don't support hard links. Once you've tried on NTFS, if you could post your findings here I can update my answer to be a more useful response for anyone else that has this issue.

Comment: Yes - I checked just after reading this last night and the USB drive is FAT32. See my edit to my original post above for the results from attempting this on my local HD.

Comment: Okay - I finally got the setup to run without error. Seems that I can do this only on a local drive. It can't be done on a USB drive (FAT32) which we discovered, but it also seems that it can't be done on a mapped network drive, which is how I was getting the second failure. When I move the entire structure to my local C: drive, **setup.py sdist** runs without error.

Comment: So it sounds like the issue still might be hard links - I'm not 100% sure if Windows supports hard links on network drives but [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx) implies there are at least some limitations. Out of interest, did you try my suggestion of removing the `os.link()` method at the top of `setup.py` when using a USB drive to see if that at least worked around the issue?

Comment: >>Out of interest, did you try my suggestion of removing the os.link() method at the top of setup.py when using a USB drive<< No, I figured that this should be done on my local drive anyway, so working around the USB issue seemed to be counter-productive. If it's relevant over-all to the difficulty I'm having, I'll be happy to give that a try.

Comment: I thought it might be interesting to try it just to try and narrow down if what you're seeing is the issue described in that bug report, even if you didn't want to end up using that as your solution. I can understand if you'd rather not spend the time, though.

Comment: Seem my edits above Cartroo - those two lines in setup.py made a difference.